# Ecommerce google analytics is not registering event

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

In header I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
var _gaq = _gaq || [];_gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-xxxxxxx-2"]);_gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);(function() {var ga = document.createElement("script");ga.type = "text/javascript";ga.async = true;ga.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js";var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);})();
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

And at the end of the body is:

```
_gaq.push(["_addTrans", "163", "XOXO E-shop", "2", "0", "0", "Bratislava", "Bratislavsky kraj", "Slovakia"]);
_gaq.push(["_addItem", "163", "01255", "ORLY BLACK 180GRIT", "Žiadna kategória", "2.00000", "1"]);
_gaq.push(["_trackTrans"]);
```

But in google anlytics is no event registered. Ecommerce is activated, code UA-xxxxxxx-2 is correct. No errors in console. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Looks legit, but you should check it with the GA Debugger Chrome extension or the Google Tag Assistant.  To exclude the obvious, did you wait a few hours after you sent your transaction ? There is a processing latency (and in my experience it takes longer for transactions than for pageviews to show up).

Comment: The code looks fine. Install GA Debugger in Chrome to ensure that the hit is going through. There is no "event" (as in GA Event) associated with your transaction either. Also, you need to wait at least 24 hours for data to show up in your GA reports.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I was not waiting at all. I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: You can check more immediately (ie. right away) with GA Debugger, or also by analysing the hits through some dev tool Network analyser.